# Is there any way, in java, to check on the status of a windows service?

Tags: java, windows-services, system-monitoring, system-status

I am looking for a library that will allow me to look up the status of a windows service to verify that the service is started and running.  I looked into the Sigar library, but it is GPL and therefor I cannot use it.  A Commercial or BSD(ish) license is required as this will be bundled into commercial software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nothing else helps, try to think of a slightly different approach (if you can, of course), e.g.:

- There is a plenty of free/non-free software which does monitoring, including Windows service monitoring (e.g. nagios, Zabbix, etc.). These monitors typically have open API where your Java app could integrate into in a number of different ways.
- If you have the control over depending service application, expose another, different way for your Java application to check (e.g. run a dummy listener on a port, create a file, etc.). Windows services aren't a cross-platform thing therefore is not something you would expect to be supported anytime soon.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any pure-Java way to do this because some operating systems don't have the notion of "services" like Windows does.  In our projects, we wrote a wrapper around calls to the "sc" command from the command line.  To get the status of a service, you can do:

> sc \\some-computer query "my service name"

You'll have to manually parse the output but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: good simple way to do this in Java

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries, but depending on how detailed you need to get you might get  by with some shell commands and parsing the output.

NET START *servicename*

will either start the service, or give you back an error message that tells you its already started.  I don't know of any command that will just give you the status though.