# Find status of Windows service from Java application?

Tags: java, windows-services

How to check the status of the windows services from a java program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way, in java, to check on the status of a windows service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127299/is-there-any-way-in-java-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-windows-service)

Comment: @Péter Török: This may be a possible dup of the question, but none of the answers to that question touched on the relatively simple ProcessBuilder-based answer I have provided.

Answer (score 10):

on the following example you can find how can you check windws service status and you can parsed to do certain action

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class doscmd 
 { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
      { 
        try 
         { 
           Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query browser"); 

BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 

           String line=reader.readLine();
           while(line!=null) 
            { 
              if(line.trim().startsWith("STATE"))

               {

                if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":")+1,line.trim().indexOf(":")+4).trim().equals("1"))
    System.out.println("Stopped");
else
    if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":")+1,line.trim().indexOf(":")+4).trim().equals("2"))
        System.out.println("Startting....");
    else
        if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":")+1,line.trim().indexOf(":")+4).trim().equals("3"))
            System.out.println("Stopping....");
        else
            if (line.trim().substring(line.trim().indexOf(":")+1,line.trim().indexOf(":")+4).trim().equals("4"))
                System.out.println("Running");

  }
   line=reader.readLine(); 
   } 

 } 

 catch(IOException e1) { } 



   } 
 }
```

Comment: The above code returns nothing. When debugged, it says access denied and null.

Answer (score 4):

At the very least you should be able to launch a cmd.exe process with the command `sc query service-name` and parse the output to determine the status.  Not pretty, but lacking a Java API to the Windows service manager this would be a viable alternative.

EDIT - Read the Javadoc for [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which will allow you to execute an external command.  You should probably set the *redirectErrorStream* property so that you don't have to handle two input streams (stdout and stderr), making for a much simpler design.

Comment: i have googled this sc query,and its works fine.can you please tell me that how can i run this query from java?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a pointer to the API you'll need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This method will return true or false depending upon service is running or not.

```
public boolean checkIfServiceRunning(String serviceName) {
    Process process;
    try {
         process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sc query " + serviceName);
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(process.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
         while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            if(reader.nextLine().contains("RUNNING")) {
               return true;
            }
         }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }            
    return false;
}
```