# How to start/stop Tomcat as a windows service from a Java program rather than just from a .bat?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, exec

I know how to start/stop Tomcat from a Java program using **BAT files** (and .sh files in linux/unix). it's done like this:

```
String command = "c:\program files\tomcat\bin\startup.bat";//for linux use .sh
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

**Note:** Use **CATALINA_HOME** to make this code more dynamic.

Now I am looking for a way to start/stop Tomcat's **Windows service** from a Java program. I mean, I want to start/stop Tomcat from Java as if I entered *Control Panel* --> *Administrative Tools* --> *Services*. 
Can it be done this way, or using **BAT files** is the maximum we can do?

I saw the question [start windows service from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075098/start-windows-service-from-java), but when I tried it with "sc" then `process.isAlive()` was **ALWAYS** `false` and when I used "net" instead of "sc" then `process.isAlive()` is always `true`, even when I used `serviceName = "aliceinwonderland"`. Sample of the code I used:

```
//String servicename = "Dhcp"; // real service that exists and started.
String serviceName = "aliceinwonderland"; // fiction, no such service
//String[] script = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "query", serviceName, "|", "find", "/C", "\"RUNNING\""};
String[] script = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "net", "query", serviceName, "|", "find", "/C", "\"RUNNING\""};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
boolean alive = process.isAlive(); // using "sc" = false; using "net" = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Windows Service Controller (`sc`) command from `cmd.exe`, like this:

```
String[] script = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "start", "Tomcat8"}; 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(script);
```

That is provided you have Tomcat service installed and named `Tomcat8`. You can check for installation instructions [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services).

Comment: Very Cool! it works.

Comment: And how can I query whether the Windows service is running (started)? I saw an existing answer, but it didn't work, see my edited question.

Comment: @BinyaminRegev you can't use `process.isAlive`, because it only checks if the process you spawned is alive (that is the `cmd.exe`, although I don't know why the answer varies for your different calls. Check out this thread for info how to check the status of a service: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388888/find-status-of-windows-service-from-java-application